# When creating a subscription in CnosDB, if the destinations part is not a list, it will panic

Tags: cnosdb

When creating a subscription, if the destinations part is not a list, it will panic.

version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision c50e379

```
➜  cnosdb-enterprise git:(main) ✗ cnosdb-cli 
CnosDB CLI v2.2.0
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "root", password: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, precision: None }
public ❯ CREATE SUBSCRIPTION test ON public DESTINATIONS ALL "127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904";

Query took 0.018 seconds.
public ❯
```

cnosdb log:

> 2023-11-07T14:53:19.446984000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription:
> Update-ing subscription: cnosdb.public.test
> 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447093000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription:
> Update-ed subscription: cnosdb.public.test
> 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447176000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription:
> Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903
> 127.0.0.1:8904"] 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447153000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations:
> ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"] 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447171000+08:00
> INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting,
> destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"]
> 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447141000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription:
> Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903
> 127.0.0.1:8904"] 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447137000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations:
> ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"] 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447202000+08:00
> INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting,
> destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"]
> 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447464000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription:
> Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903
> 127.0.0.1:8904"] 2023-11-07T14:53:19.447308000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations:
> ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"] The application panicked (crashed).
> Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
> InvalidUri(InvalidUriChar) Location:
> coordinator/src/subscription.rs:235
>
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
> ⋮ 10 frames hidden ⋮                                 11:
> coordinator::subscription::SubscriptionService::send_to_destination::{{closure}}::h2e4c96d3d075bd34
> at :   12: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::h6232cf87137989d3
> at :   13: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::Context::run_task::h47d6f1ce70b80ea6
> at :   14: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::run::h01f7d052d389905f
> at :   15: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::h20df62bfae0681f8
> at :   16: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h0cb9a5736f1dc2ab
> at :   17: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h2c7aec67e606f82e
> at :   18: std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h5343322b5f9311e3
> at :   19: __pthread_joiner_wake
> at :
>
> Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame
> filtering. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.